# Expressing an Imperative Without Knowing the Imperative

Tags: перевод

Is there an alternative way to order someone if you don't know how to form the imperative out of a certain word? For example, I might want to say, "Don't smoke!" but I can't come up with "Не кури!"

Answer (score 3):

You could say `Не курить!`. It sounds more like an order than `Не кури!`.
Another example: `Don't make noise!` => `Не шуметь!` instead of `Не шуми!`

Answer (score 3):

Colloquially either *Здесь не курят* or *Здесь курить нельзя*.

If we talk about formal (written) prohibition then "*Курение запрещено*" or "*Курить запрещено*".

As generic construction, one may also use *не нужно* + *any infinitive* to avoid the imperative at all.

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot of possible expressions without imperative, unfortunately those are also unlikely to help in that particular case.

```
Не надо здесь курить!
```

`Не могли бы вы в сторонке покурить?`

```
Здесь нельзя курить. По новому закону - 15 метров от остановки.

Может, перестанешь курить (при детях)?
```